# How to update a field when another is modified

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I have three fields 
1. Price (:P7_PRIJS)
2. Quantity (:P7_HOEVEELHEID)
3. Total (:P7_TOTAAL).

I want the total to be updated (price * quantity) the moment the quantity is changed. All items are on the same region, from the same table.

I have already created a trigger to update the total, this works, but is not visible in the screen.

I have tried with a Dynamic action, but get errors when doing so.

I just want to see in the form, before saving the updated total. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic action **is** a way to do that. Actually, you need two of them (which will look exactly the same), each of them created on `P7_PRIJS` and `P7_HOEVEELHEID` items (so that total gets calculated regardless of which item value you've changed).

Dynamic action's action is **Set value**:

- set type: PL/SQL expression
- PL/SQL expression: `:P7_PRIJS * :P7_HOEVEELHEID`
- items to submit: `P7_PRIJS,P7_HOEVEELHEID`
- affected elements: item, `P7_TOTAAL`

Comment: **GREAT** Littlefoot! This worked! I had tried the PL/SQL expression before, but had no idea what to fill in. I just did as you suggested, and it works.